# parsing from API Array of array

Tags: swift

I have a view that has collectionView & table view. Collection view will fill array of dates and table view will fetch a list of topics based on selected date from collection view 
[image]

and from API this is the response

```
{
"responseCode": 1,
"responseMessage": "success",
"Version": "1.0",
"result": [
    {
        "name": "2018-10-12",
        "workShops": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "timeschedule": "12:12 - 13:12",
                "title": "title 1",
                "showTimeEn": "10 min",
                "ageEn": "3ews",
                "durEn": "10 min",
                "speakerEn": "1111",
                "locationEn": "location",
                "workshopImg": "img.png"
             }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "2018-10-13",
        "workShops": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "timeschedule": "12:12 - 13:12",
                "title": "title 1",
                "showTimeEn": "10 min",
                "ageEn": "3ews",
                "durEn": "10 min",
                "speakerEn": "1111",
                "locationEn": "location",
                "workshopImg": "img.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "2018-10-14",
        "workShops": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "timeschedule": "12:12 - 13:12",
                "title": "title 1",
                "showTimeEn": "10 min",
                "ageEn": "3ews",
                "durEn": "10 min",
                "speakerEn": "1111",
                "locationEn": "location",
                "workshopImg": "img.png"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "timeschedule": "12:12 - 13:12",
                "title": "title 1",
                "showTimeEn": "10 min",
                "ageEn": "3ews",
                "durEn": "10 min",
                "speakerEn": "1111",
                "locationEn": "location",
                "workshopImg": "img.png"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

}

i created model with 3 Classes that called "WorkshopModel","WorkshopResult" and "Workshop"
i need to know first how can i do it please

```
    func getData(completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){
    if appDelegate.isConnectedToNetwork(){
        //loadIndicatior()
        let url            = URL_
        var request        = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in

            //print("Success: \(response)")
            switch response.result{
            case .success( _):
                if let statusCode: Int = response.response?.statusCode {
                    switch statusCode{
                    case 200:

                        if let JSON = response.result.value{
                            let inboxValue : SICFFWorkshopModel = SICFFWorkshopModel.init(object: JSON as AnyObject)

                            self._workshopDates = inboxValue.result!

                            for _topc in self._workshopDates{
                                for confs in _topc.workShops!{
                                self._workshopDetals.append(confs)
                                }
                            }
                            print("Taalab, ", self._workshopDetals.count)
                            self.tblView.reloadData()
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            self.stopAnimating()
                        }else{
                            self.stopAnimating()
                            print("Error In Server")
                        }
                        completionHandler(true)

                        break
                    case 404:
                        completionHandler(true)

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Alert", comment: "nothing"), message: NSLocalizedString("Server Error", comment: "nothing"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Click", comment: "nothing"), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


                        break

                    default:
                        completionHandler(false)
                        break
                    }
                    break
                }
            case .failure:
                completionHandler(false)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

}

the problem is the table view is displaying the all topics array 
i need to knw if my code for feching data is already correct and how can i handel it from table view

table View code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return self._workshopDetals.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WorkshopTableViewCell
    let _data = self._workshopDetals[indexPath.row]



        cell.lblEventName.text =  _data.titleEn
        cell.lblTime.text =  _data.timeschedule

    return cell
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ? what you have tried ?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Show me your code of tableview

Comment: updated on the question

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier if you tried this

```
struct WorkshopModel:Decodable {
  let  responseCode: Int
  let  responseMessage:String
  let  Version: String  
  let  result:[WorkshopResult]
}
```

//

```
struct WorkshopResult:Decodable {
  let  name : String 
  let  workShops:[Workshop]
}
```

//

```
struct Workshop:Decodable{
   let   id:String
   let   timeschedule: String
   let   title: String
   let   showTimeEn: String
   let   ageEn: String
   let   durEn: String
   let   speakerEn: String
   let   locationEn: String
   let   workshopImg: String
}
```

//

```
do {
   let items = try JSONDecoder().decode(WorkshopModel.self, from: data)
   print(items.result)
}
catch {
  print(error)
}
```